How long does Azure Durable Function raise-event store the event to in-memory buffer?
Based on the documentation, for raise event,
Internally, the "raise-event" API enqueues a message that gets picked up by the waiting orchestrator function. If the instance is not waiting on the specified event name, the event message is added to an in-memory buffer. If the orchestration instance later begins listening for that event name, it will check the buffer for event messages and trigger the task that was waiting for it.
Based on this statement, if the instance is not in waiting state, then the event gets put in-memory buffer. Does it mean that its not persisted anywhere? And if not, is there a chance that the event is lost if the system restarts or crash?
And if it is persisted, where it does stays and how long does it last?
My current scenario is that, the main orchestrator havent call WaitForExternalEvent function and sub orchestrator already calls RaiseEventAsync. I wonder if theres possibility that the main orchestrator goes into wait status indefinitely.
Thanks.


And if it is persisted, where it does stays and how long does it last?


The events will remain in the durable storage until they are explicitly removed or until they expire based on the retention policies set for the storage account.

Regarding your scenario where the main orchestrator hasn't called WaitForExternalEvent and a sub-orchestrator has already raised an event using RaiseEventAsync. the main orchestrator will only transition to a waiting state if it actively waits for an event.

The main orchestrator will call the sub-orchestrator, which will raise an event. The main orchestrator will wait for this event and perform some action once it receives the event.


Orchestrator Function:
[FunctionName("MainOrchestrator")]
public static async Task RunOrchestrator(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    // Call the sub-orchestrator
    await context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync("SubOrchestratorFunction", null);

    // Wait for an event
    string eventData = await context.WaitForExternalEvent<string>("MyEvent");

    // Once the event is received, log it
    log.LogInformation($"Received event: {eventData}");
}

The below Sub-Orchestrator function will raise an event.
[FunctionName("SubOrchestratorFunction")]
public static async Task RunSubOrchestrator(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    // Raise an event
    await context.CallActivityAsync("RaiseEventActivity", null);
}


The above example indicates how events are handled in Azure Durable Functions. The main orchestrator waits for an event using WaitForExternalEvent, and the event is raised by the sub-orchestrator using RaiseEventAsync.

Activity Function will raise the event using RaiseEventAsync like below:


[FunctionName("RaiseEventAsyncFunction")]
public static async Task RaiseEventAsyncFunction(
    [ActivityTrigger] string eventData,
    [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient client)
{
    // Raise the event
    await client.RaiseEventAsync("MainOrchestrator", "MyEvent", eventData);
}


The events will remain in the durable storage until they are explicitly removed or until they expire based on the retention policies set for the storage account.
For your statement over here, can share if theres an official documentation on it? And where do we set the retention policies?
Thanks.
